If the slope of a measurable function is always irrational, is the function linear?
If $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function, such that all distinct $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$$
Can we conclude that $f$ is a linear function?
This is If the slope of a secant is always irrational, is the function linear? with the assumption that $f$ is measurable added. There the answer was shown to be yes, if $f$ is continuous and no in general, by an axiom of choice argument. It reminded me of the old question (of interest to Steinhaus and his circle) about whether $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ implies $f$ is of the form $f(x)=kx$. If memory serves, the answer in this case is affirmative for measurable $f$ and no in general, by an axiom of choice argument.

Here is a link to a question showing an additive measurable function is necessarily linear, as the OP mentioned: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556018/simple-proof-that-a-lebesgue-measurable-and-additive-function-is-linear

Here is a counterexample:
Lemma: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a countable set. Then there exists a co-countable (and therefore nonempty and measurable) $B \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $A \cap (B - B^c) = \varnothing$.
Proof: Let $B = \langle A \rangle^c$, where $\langle A \rangle$ is the additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $A$, which is countable. If $b \in B$, $c \in B^c = \langle A \rangle$ is s.t. $a = b - c \in A$, then $b = c + a \in \langle A \rangle = B^c$, a contradiction. $\square$
Now, pick an arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}^c$. Let $A = \frac{1}{\mathbb{Q} - \lambda}$, which is countable, and $B \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ be given by the lemma above. Since $A \cap (B - B^c) = \varnothing$, we have $\mathbb{Q} \cap (\lambda + \frac{1}{B - B^c}) = \varnothing$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \lambda x + 1_B(x)$. Clearly, $f$ is measurable. As $B$ is neither empty nor the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is not a linear function. Moreover, we have,

If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \neq y$, are both in $B$, or both in $B^c$, then $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = \lambda \notin \mathbb{Q}$;
If $x \in B$, $y \in B^c$, then $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = \lambda + \frac{1}{x - y} \in \lambda + \frac{1}{B - B^c}$, so $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \notin \mathbb{Q}$;
Similarly, if $x \in B^c$, $y \in B$, then $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = \lambda - \frac{1}{x - y} = \lambda + \frac{1}{y - x} \in \lambda + \frac{1}{B - B^c}$, so $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

